# Why is this basic HTML code not working as it should

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

First of all I'm new and I need a little help to fix this basic HTML code , 
the code is :

```
  <head>
<title>
  Shared column border
</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
<!--
#left { width: 5px; float: left;
border-right: 8px solid #444 }
#right { margin-left: 500px;
border-left: 8px solid #0b9cef }
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>Secure Client Area- Portal</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>Urgent Delivery Available</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>100% Manual Photo Editing</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>SSL Secured Image Transfer</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>Monthly Payment Plan</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
  "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
  height="20" /> <big>Variety of Payment Methods</big>
</p>
<div id="right">
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>100% Satisfaction Gauranteed</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>Money-Back Gaurantee</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>Right Price &amp; Best
    Quality</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>12hr Quick Turnaround Time</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>Volume Discount Up to 20%</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
    "20" height="20" /> <big>365 Days Operation Enabled</big>
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to 2nd column in the same position as the 1st column is in. 
+
I want some space between the blue separator / divider & 2nd column

Can anyone help me to fix this or Can anyone teach me how to do this ? 
as I said I'm new so looking forward for some guidance !

Comment: Holy smokes I haven't seen CDATA in a while! <big>! What do you mean by second column? You will want to use CSS to fix this, but it's not clear what the intended layout is. Can you draw a little picture?

Comment: I think you forgot to wrap your "first column" elements in a `div` that has ID `left`(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not using the styling rule `#left` that has `float:left` anywhwere. So no floating is happening to the `p` elements.
Then you are wrapping your second column with a `<div id="right">` and the `#right` styling ruke has no float in it. Thats why the `<p>` elements are displaying as blocks and not aligning next to each other. Maybe wrap the first column with `<div id="left">` and use the following for your `#left` css rule :

```
#left {
        float: left;
        border-right: 8px solid #444;
        padding-right: 25px // added some padding distance between the content and right border
    }
```

Second point, for

> I want some space between the blue separator / divider & 2nd column

you can use `padding` (refer to this article to see the difference between padding and margin : [Margin vs Padding](https://medium.com/frontendshortcut/margin-vs-padding-c1fc8ea8bfaf).

Here's your updated code to provide what you need (note that I added 25px padding ditance beween the blue border and the content, and 25px distance between the left colulmn and the right one.)

```
<head>
<title>
    Shared column border
</title>
<style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    <!--
    #left {
        float: left;
        border-right: 8px solid #444;
        padding-right: 25px
    }

    #right {
        border-left: 8px solid #0b9cef;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 25px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    /*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <p>
            <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242"  src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>Secure Client Area- Portal</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>Urgent Delivery Available</big>
        </p>
        <p>
            <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>100% Manual Photo Editing</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>SSL Secured Image Transfer</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>Monthly Payment Plan</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20"
         height="20"/> <big>Variety of Payment Methods</big>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>100% Satisfaction Gauranteed</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>Money-Back Gaurantee</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>Right Price &amp; Best
        Quality</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>12hr Quick Turnaround Time</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>Volume Discount Up to 20%</big>
        </p>
        <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src=
    "https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width=
         "20" height="20"/> <big>365 Days Operation Enabled</big>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To adjust that blue line on the left you will need to add padding to the left ( I made it 10px but you can adjust it)
And set the width of the left to look good for you.
Here is the code

```html
<body>
 
<title>
  Shared column border
</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
<!--
#left {
    width: 300px;
    
    float: left;
 border-right: 8px solid #444 }
    
    
#right {
    margin-left: 500px;
 border-left: 8px solid #0b9cef; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
/*]]>*/
</style>

<div id="left">
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Secure Client Area- Portal</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Urgent Delivery Available</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>100% Manual Photo Editing</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>SSL Secured Image Transfer</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Monthly Payment Plan</big>
</p>
<p>
  <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Variety of Payment Methods</big>
</p>
    </div>
<div id="right">
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>100% Satisfaction Gauranteed</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Money-Back Gaurantee</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Right Price &amp; Best
    Quality</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>12hr Quick Turnaround Time</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>Volume Discount Up to 20%</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-5242" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNJHq645/1398913.png" alt="" width="20" height="20"> <big>365 Days Operation Enabled</big>
  </p>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Paste it into your editor and open it in browser because there is not enough space here to fit all the stuff.

Comment: If you want to learn to do this sorts of stuff better get your hands on some frameworks like bootstrap or foundation to help you.